# wrapping web site

Tags: mobile, web-applications

Using [hosted web app solution](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm?WT.mc_id=16585-DEV-codeproject-article70), you can easily wrap any existing website and create Widows App.

The same you can do for Andriod and iOS using [manifoldjs](http://www.manifoldjs.com/).

So I can create many hosted apps, ad some ads and put in apps stores. Do I need some agreement with owner of the site?

I asked [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272288/do-i-need-to-make-an-agreement-with-stack-exchange-to-create-an-app) and Stack Exchange don't require any agreement, but what about others?

Comment: Yes! Of course you do. It is the copyrighted property of the site owner and content creator. You can get sued into oblivion is you do not. Certainly, Google, Bing, Yahoo!, Yandex, Baidu, and others will refuse to include your site into their search engines with enough DMCA complaints even from a single source.

Comment: when I create hosted web app, it isn't web site, it's app, which just I put to app store, I don't need to worry about search engines. Other thing that app stories can refuse to accept it in case of owner complain.

Comment: No. It is someones copyrighted property. It is fully illegal in most countries and will open you up to serious law suits that will traverse borders. You can only use sites that allow their content to be used openly such as SE. Otherwise, don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using hosted web app solution, you can easily wrap any existing website and create Widows App.....So I can create many hosted apps, ad some ads and put in apps stores. Do I need some agreement with owner of the site?

As closetnoc pointed out...

**YES**

If you plan on turning websites into apps, you need to at least have full rights to that websites or at least sufficient rights depending on the agreements the owners of each website has with you or the general public.

These agreements are sometimes known as "terms and conditions" and is often available as a separate page on professional websites.

Comment: my idea to get easy money failed :(

Comment: Better to have your idea failed than you jailed for illegally making money.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is far more gray than most seem to realize. That is one of the major flaws of existing ip law.

If you propose an app that formats information drawn directly from the web, it's likely that you are only going to run afoul of their trademark rights, not their copyrights.

Why?

Copyright:
They are presenting that information to the web. You aren't providing access to something that the user doesn't have access to. In fact, as lazy as you make this sound, you are probably not even copying anything.

Trademark:
Trademarks are legal identifications that protect entities from others deceiving the public about the source of goods and relations to products and services. More or less.

To avoid that legal issue would require making it obvious that you are doing what you are doing and are not actually affiliated with these people.

If you did that, it probably would be legal. Not sure why anyone would want your product, but there you go.

Confusion is a trademark issue. Significance of a copied section is a copyright issue. They are distinct types off intellectual property laws.